# Parsing iCal feed with Python using icalendar

Tags: python, icalendar

I'm trying to parse a feed with multiple events using the icalendar lib in python.

'summary' , 'description' and so on works fine, but for 'dtstart' and 'dtend' it's returning me:
`icalendar.prop.vDDDTypes object at 0x101be62d0`

```
def calTest():
    req = urllib2.Request('https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/XXXXXXXXXX/basic.ics')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    data = response.read()

    cal = Calendar.from_ical(data)

    for event in cal.walk('vevent'):

        date = event.get('dtstart')
        summery = event.get('summary')

        print str(date)
        print str(summery)

    return
```

What am I doing wrong?
To use vobject its not a option, have to use the icalendar lib.
Many thanks for any help for a python rookie.

Comment: So maybe it's a `icalendar.prop.vDDDTypes` object. What's the problem?

Comment: spelling mistake, summery

Answer (score 41):

The objects representing `dtstart` and `dtend` have an attribute `dt` which contains a standard `datetime.datetime` object.

```
start = event.get('dtstart')
print(start.dt)
```

Comment: It's astonishing that no one upvoted this answer until now :-)

Comment: and where can one find this information in the docs?! this was driving me crazy till I found this answer!

Comment: @benzkji Most probably I got it directly from the sourcecode

Answer (score 5):

A little late here, but if that helps:
the API has been updated since (I did the same mistake // copy pasting another stackoverflow post) You need to use the method decoded() instead of get()

You can find the latest API reference to icalendar here : http://icalendar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

replace your call to get by decoded :

```
date = event.decoded('dtstart')
summery = event.decoded('summary')
```

It should work.

Comment: it doesnt work, returning: `'Event' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: @user912830823, I imagine you've figured this out in the 5 years since you left this comment, but you have a typo in your code. Should be `decoded`, not `decode`.

Answer (score -4):

From the [official documentation](http://icalendar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#value-types) you can access the values of `dtstart` and `dtend` like this -

```
date = event.get('dtstart')
print date.to_ical()
```

they are `icalendar.prop.vDDDTypes` objects. Neither string and nor do they have a intuitive `__str__()` method, it seems. Hence you got that output.

Please read the documentation.