# Sorting icalendar events chronologically

Tags: python, icalendar

I need to convert a large set of ics icalendar events into a LaTeX pgfgantt chart. For this I wrote a tiny script with the help of an answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937754/parsing-ical-feed-with-python-using-icalendar).

```
from icalendar import Calendar, Event
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import UTC # timezone

g = open('calendar.ics','rb')
gcal = Calendar.from_ical(g.read())
for component in gcal.walk():
    if component.name == "VEVENT":
        start = component.get('dtstart')
        end = component.get('dtend')
        print("\ganttbar{"+ str(component.get('summary')) + "}{" + str(start.dt) + "}{" + str(end.dt) + "}\\\\")
g.close()
```

The path has to be absolute for some reason.

Comment: For us to help you, provide a minimal reproducible problem set containing sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. What you have provided falls short of this goal. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's add the data into pandas and  try to sort them according to the start date.

```
from icalendar import Calendar, Event
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import UTC # timezone
import pandas 

g = open('calendar.ics','rb')
gcal = Calendar.from_ical(g.read())
calevents = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['Event','Start','End',])
for component in gcal.walk():
    if component.name == "VEVENT":
        start = component.get('dtstart')
        end = component.get('dtend')
        calevents.loc[len(calevents)] = [component.get('summary'), start.dt, end.dt] 
g.close()
calevents['Start'] = pandas.to_datetime(calevents['Start'])
calevents = calevents.sort_values(by='Start', ignore_index=True)
for index in range(len(calevents)):
    print("\ganttbar{" + str(calevents.loc[index,"Event"]) + "}{" + str(calevents.loc[index,"Start"]) + "}{" + str(calevents.loc[index,"End"]) + "}\\\\")
```

Almost there, but the first date now contains a time. Can be removed in the output by removing ' 00:00:00'.